# How can I programmatically dismiss/disable the screenshot popover that was introduced in iOS 11?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, ios11

In my application, I have functionality where I detect when a user takes a screenshot, then I present this screenshot for annotation and markup.

The appearance of the instant markup popover confuses the user and reduces UX quality in my app for this feature, as the user might not know which screenshot to annotate. Also the popover will cover a part of the screenshot that is supposed to be annotated.

Is there a way I can **dismiss** this popover or **prevent it** from appearing at all while the user is using the application?

I tried to go through the documentation of new/existing iOS APIs to figure out where this happens, but with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I submitted an issue to apple's radar and got the following response:

> Hi Aly,
>
> This is a courtesy email regarding Bug ID# 32707749.
>
> Engineering has provided the following feedback regarding this issue:
>
> Thank you for your feedback, it is noted. Engineering has determined
>   that there are currently **no plans to address this issue**.
>
> We are now closing this bug report.
>
> If you have questions or comments about the resolution, please update
>   your bug report with that information so we can respond.

This is the issue's replica on openradar:
http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=4941591483514880

I guess this is it for now.